# Migrations with SequelizeJS and CLI

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js, sequelize-cli

Currently I have started working on NODE JS where I am using the [SEQUELIZE ORM](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/). The Sequelize does support the migrations using [sequelize-cli](https://github.com/sequelize/cli), but the documentation does not explain every details around how it should be used of migrations. I want to know if following are possible using Sequelize CLI. The following points are important considering the PROD deployment

1. Auto generate migration file by looking at model
2. Auto generate migration file based new changes made to model
3. Generate the SQL script of migration so that we can run this on PROD
4. Environment specific migrations(Dev,Stage,Prod

I have gone through the documentation but it does not explian any of the point mentioned above. Please help me with this, I

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The idea with using migrations is that they are the king of your database. They are the only thing that changes your database schema, and the only way you should be changing your database schema is by simply running the migrations.

In answer to your questions:

**1. Auto generate migration file by looking at model**

Don't. Manually generate a migration. If you're changing the columns of a particular table, generate the migration first, then modify the corresponding model next. Migrations are king of the database. Models come second.

**2. Auto generate migration file based new changes made to model**

Don't. Same as above.

**3. Generate the SQL script of migration so that we can run this on PROD**

Don't. You should just be able to run the migrations themselves directly on production, connecting to the production database, just the same as you'd run them in dev, with `sequelize db:migrate`. Your deployment script should automatically run `sequelize db:migrate` on the production database every time you push new code to production.

**4. Environment specific migrations(Dev,Stage,Prod)**

Definitely don't. Every migration should run in every environment. Your database should have the same schema regardless of the environment.

Update: Here's an example migartion that works (both running up and down) to add a new boolean column:

```
'use strict';

module.exports = {
  up: function (queryInterface, Sequelize) {
    return queryInterface.addColumn(
      'my_table',
      'my_new_column',
      {
        type: Sequelize.BOOLEAN,
      }
    )
  },

  down: function (queryInterface, Sequelize) {
    return queryInterface.removeColumn('my_table', 'my_new_column')
  }
};
```

Comment: Thanks so much @joshua.paling now i have the good idea of sequelize migrations and I understand my role in it. Now that i will be wrting the migrations, I see 2 ways to it. 1. Using sequelize api 2. Sql scripts. I think the second approach would be more cleaner as I will be writing sql queries in opposition to api.. as the api are not well documented i dont feel confident using them.. i tried one migration using api when i added column to table.. but when i trying undoing it.. migration did not removed the column.. this made me think of sql queries. Cn u plz suggest your recommendation on this

Comment: Ideally you should use sequelize API. The main benefit of this is that your migrations should work regardless of which database you're using (eg, MySQL, Postgres, etc). If sequelize's API doesn't support what you want to do, then writing plain SQL is OK. In terms of updating and dropping a column, I'll update my answer with an example migartion that works for me.

Comment: Thanks so much @joshua.paling . I really appreciate your all the efforts. And I agree on the fact that where ever it seems tricks to write migrations using API, we should use plain SQL.  Thanks again ! :)